# How to parse nested map properly and show it in the listview.builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to parse this API response below and showing the languages in a listview. But getting this error message in the itemCount section:

Class 'Data' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Data'
Tried calling: length

How can I fix this?

Here is my endpoint response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "tr": "Türkçe",
        "en": "English",
        "de": "Deutsch",
        "fr": "Français",
        "it": "Italiano",
        "es": "Espanol",
        "ru": "Русский язык",
        "ar": "العربية",
        "fa": "فارسى",
        "ja": "日本語",
        "el": "ελληνικά",
        "ko": "한국어 [韓國語]",
        "zh": "中文",
        "uk": "Українська",
        "isiteng": "İşaret Dili"
    }
}
```

I parse this in https://app.quicktype.io/ and here is the created model file:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final languages = languagesFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Languages languagesFromJson(String str) => Languages.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String languagesToJson(Languages data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Languages {
    Languages({
        this.data,
    });

    Data data;

    factory Languages.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Languages(
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": data.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
    Data({
        this.tr,
        this.en,
        this.de,
        this.fr,
        this.it,
        this.es,
        this.ru,
        this.ar,
        this.fa,
        this.ja,
        this.el,
        this.ko,
        this.zh,
        this.uk,
        this.isiteng,
    });

    String tr;
    String en;
    String de;
    String fr;
    String it;
    String es;
    String ru;
    String ar;
    String fa;
    String ja;
    String el;
    String ko;
    String zh;
    String uk;
    String isiteng;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        tr: json["tr"],
        en: json["en"],
        de: json["de"],
        fr: json["fr"],
        it: json["it"],
        es: json["es"],
        ru: json["ru"],
        ar: json["ar"],
        fa: json["fa"],
        ja: json["ja"],
        el: json["el"],
        ko: json["ko"],
        zh: json["zh"],
        uk: json["uk"],
        isiteng: json["isiteng"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tr": tr,
        "en": en,
        "de": de,
        "fr": fr,
        "it": it,
        "es": es,
        "ru": ru,
        "ar": ar,
        "fa": fa,
        "ja": ja,
        "el": el,
        "ko": ko,
        "zh": zh,
        "uk": uk,
        "isiteng": isiteng,
    };
}
```

My service file:

```
class LanguagesService {
  Future getLanguages() async {
    try {
      // headers of the post request

      final _headers = {
        //todo bearer token
        'Authorization': hardCodedBearerToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      };

      // sending post request
      http.Response response = await http.get(
        loginAPIURL,
        headers: _headers
      );

      //get response from endpoint
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('$loginAPIURL Endpoint Response: response.body');
        print(response.body);

        Languages lang = await Languages.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        
        return lang;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return throw Exception("LANGUAGES NOT TAKEN");
    }
  }
}
```

my languages_screen file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_vom/helpers/color_book.dart';
import 'package:the_vom/models/languages_model.dart';
import 'package:the_vom/services/languages_service.dart';

class LanguagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LanguagesScreenState createState() => _LanguagesScreenState();
}

class _LanguagesScreenState extends State<LanguagesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Select your language"),
        backgroundColor: ColorBook.appBarColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: LanguagesService().getLanguages(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          // controller: _scrollController,
                          reverse: true,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Card(
                                  elevation: 5,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListTile(
                                        dense: false,
                                        title: Text(
                                            snapshot.data[index].toString()),
                                        subtitle: Text('subtitle'),
                                        trailing: Text('trailing'),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    : CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot.data.data` returns a value with type `Data` not `List`. You can parse the data differently way:

First, create a Language class thats contains a language code and name.

```dart
class Language {
  final String? code;
  final String? name;

  Language({this.code, this.name});
}
```

Then, create LanguageData class (rename as your preference) thats contains tha list of languages:

```dart
class LanguagesData {
  final List<Language>? languages;

  LanguagesData({
    this.languages
  });

  factory LanguagesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final List<Language> languages = json["data"].keys.map<Language>((code) => Language(
      code: code,
      name: json["data"][code],
    )).toList();

    return LanguagesData(languages: languages);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Update service:

```dart
//...
LanguagesData lang = await LanguagesData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
/...
```

Updates ListViewBuilder:

```dart
// ...
itemCount: snapshot.data?.languages.length,
// ...
title: Text(snapshot.data?.languages[index]?.name),
//...
```

Comment: is this going to be the model file's latest version?

Comment: Yes, as long as the data structure of the service does not change

Comment: cant share the code in the comments. could you please take a look at here: https://snippi.com/s/hu1r66o . I implement the changes you made but it returns this: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Language>'

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about something. I have updated my answer

Comment: thank you very much! One last thing I'm asking out of curiosity. Is there any way to print these list from reverse order?

Comment: Yeah, in this part: `return LanguagesData(languages: languages);` change to `return LanguagesData(languages: languages.reversed);`